NextJS application deployed on Firebase Hosting unable to find i18next file
I'm using Firebase Hosting to deploy a Next.js application which utilizes getServerSideProps for server-side rendering. Below are some relevant parts of firebase.json:
"hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "targets": {
      "staging": {
        "hosting": {
          "staging": ["staging-env"]
        }
      }
    },
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-east1"
    }
  },
  "i18n": {
    "root": "/locales"
  }

I have a next-i18next.config.js file containing the following:
i18n: {
  defaultLocale: "en",
  locales: ["en", "fr"]
},

Meanwhile, part of next.config.mjs looks like this:
const nextConfig = {
  i18n,
  typescript: {
    tsconfigPath,
    ignoreBuildErrors: true
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ["@spotwork/ui"]
}

I deploy my hosting using firebase deploy --only hosting and it is building and deploying the application. The problem is, when I open my app, sign in (using google APIs), it will give me a 500 error trying to find a SSR page /companies/:id/shift. Upon checking GCP logging, I see the following error:
Error: next-i18next was unable to find a user config at /workspace/next-i18next.config.js
    at _callee$ (/workspace/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js:110:17)
    at tryCatch (/workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
    at Generator.next (/workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:17)
    at _next (/workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:9)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:12
    at serverSideTranslations (/workspace/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js:183:17)

I used firebase's documentation to check if my i18n-next configuration is okay and it does seem to be that way. I have no idea why it's breaking and what to do about it.
Appreciate your time and effort!
